# Pass Account id (parent) to User (child) with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have set up the necessary models and views to have a Devise resource, Account and User. Account has_many users & User belongs_to account. The schema reflects account_id as an attribute of user. I'm probably mistaken but I was under the impression that this account_id attribute would automatically be filled when an Account is logged in & creates a new user. Upon checking the Rails console, it seems all new users created this way had a nil value for account_id. Separate question but is this the ideal way to have multitenancy in an application using Devise?

Models:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :users   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end
```

account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account, :dependent => :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  has_many :projects

end
```

schema.rb (just users & accounts)

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.boolean  "supervisor"
    t.string   "name"
  end
create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user! 
    def new     
        @user = User.new   
    end    

    def create         
      @user.skip_confirmation! # confirm immediately--don't require email confirmation     
      if @user.save       
        flash[:success] = "User added and activated."       
        redirect_to users_path # list of all users     
      else       
        render 'new'     
      end   
    end

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

end
```

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new     
    @accounts = Account.new     
    @accounts.users.build  
  end    
  def create     
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])     
    if @account.save       
      flash[:success] = "Account created"       
      redirect_to accounts_path     
    else       
      render 'new'     
    end   
  end
end
```

from registrations > edit.html.erb

```
<% if account_signed_in? %>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <span><%= link_to "Add user", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm working on a similar project and interested if you found a solution. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what how exactly you are trying to create a user

But creating a user with

```
@account.users.build
```

would automatically add account_id to user object.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In my UsersController, I replaced "@user = User.new" with "@account.users.build" but the console still tells me the account_id is nil. Since it's not happening automatically, there must be some larger issue I can't figure out. If you have any other suggestion, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm surprised! If account persists in DB then "@account.users.build" surely adds account_id in user object!
If @account is new record then account_id could be nil, but that doesn't seem to be the case with you.